# Cosa significa "formule collaudate" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> La sera stessa, dopo la telefonata a Stefano, ce ne andammo tutt’e quattro in spiaggia a passeggiare e poi ci sedemmo sulla sabbia fredda e ci stendemmo a guardare le stelle, Lila poggiata sui gomiti, Nino con la testa sul suo stomaco, io con la testa sullo stomaco di Nino, Bruno con la testa sul mio stomaco. Stemmo con gli occhi alle costellazioni, e usammo **formule collaudate** in lode dell’architettura portentosa del cielo.

Malgrado abbia cercato il verbo "collaudare" in alcuni dizionari, non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "formule collaudate" in questo brano. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: In questo contesto “frasi fatte”.

Comment: Se posso aggiungere: frasi fatte, note, molto usate. Si dice "collaudato" di qualcosa i cui effetti (positivi) sono stati più volte verificati.

Comment: Corrisponde a «fig., di oggetto, lavoro (manuale o d’ingegno) o anche di persona, che abbia dato ormai di sé buona prova: è un sistema, un metodo (e fig. un cuoco) ormai collaudato» (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/collaudare/). Ora, se solo qualche anima mia mettesse il tutto insieme in una risposta...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'aggettivo ***[collaudato](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/collaudato)*** viene usato in senso figurato, con il significato di "frasi fatte solitamente usate in queste circostanze" (la contemplazione della volta celeste):

> - agg.  estens., fig., ***che ha dimostrato nel tempo la sua validità; di provato e sicuro rendimento:***
>
>   - *un metodo collaudato di vendita, è una ricetta collaudata, ti puoi fidare; di notevole stabilità: un matrimonio collaudato; di assoluta fiducia: un amico collaudato*

(De Mauro)